# Add a plus sign to every word in a cell using Excel or Google SpreadSheets formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a column with the name of different products, for example:

```
   A
1 red car
2 blue whale
3 red carpet in the closet
4 star wars dvd extra especial thing
5 whatever with your however
```

I would like in column B:

```
    B
1 +red +car
2 +blue +whale
3 +red +carpet +in +the +closet
4 +star +wars +dvd +extra +especial +thing
5 +whatever +with +your +however
```

I´m using Google Spreadsheets, but a solution to Excel would work just fine!

If the only way to accomplish that is using a custom formula, I would prefer a Google Spreadsheets formula. Although, I would really like to know a native formula if possible.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but it's worth noting that if the reason you are doing this is to create Modified Broad Match keywords for Google Ads (formerly Adwords), MBM is being phased out as of July 2021 and its behavior folded into phrase match: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/10346549.

The phrase match is easier to write, since it is just "phrase in quotes"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go. Put this in cell B1:

```
="+"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," "," +")
```

Now copy downward.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid have to fill-down and have to repeat this as new data is entered, on Google Sheets try

```
=ArrayFormula("+"&REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(E:E,LEN(E:E))," "," \+") )
```